# Magento Override Shipping Methods

Tags: php, magento

In Magento Admin Panel, following shipping methods are enabled

- Flat Rate
- Free Shipping

But when check out, both of the shipping method aren't shown and there are other methods which didn't set from Admin panel are shown.

Where can I find those Override Shipping Methods? Where it's possibly located?

I am using Magento Version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Which Shipping methods are showing ?

Comment: Currently, it's showing like Custom Shipping with the fixed price. Titles are set custom and it doesn't what it has written in the admin panel.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your shipping methods configuration and one of the shipping method selection in the checkout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default shipping method `flat rate` and `free shipping` are defined in 
app/code/core/Mage/Shipping

In this open etc/config.xml file and find appropriate model for it. In the model file you will find default methods attached to the carrier.

If it's been overridden, then the simplest way to find it is by a doing file search in your magento directory by "flat rate" or "free shipping".

However your other shipping carrier and methods like fedex, ups, usps etc are defined in app/code/core/Mage/Usa

If you have trouble finding the method then try with overriding it by your methods.

If you have any issue let me know I will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a multistore set up?  In which case, these options are possibly configured against the individual store view!  Please take a look using the drop down in the top left of the admin configuration screen.  Switch to the correct store scope and check delivery options there.

Comment: I don't have multistore set up. That's what confusing me most.

Answer (score 2):

You should first confirm that whether any external extension or code customization causes this problem or not.

Then after you can confirm that both of these Magento shipping method are enabled in backend.

May be you have other shipping method related extension installed in system.

Please have a look in it. You can find all modules in `app/etc/modules` directory.

Answer (score 2):

for creating custom shipping method check

```
http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/
```

or try to install one from magento connect, as this one

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping.html
```